# Is it possible peer to peer connection over WAN without any server?

Tags: java, sockets, wan, peer

I need to send a file from computer to computer in Java. I do it in a local network with a server/client model. But is it possible to do that over wide area network?

Clients might under the [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). I send manually the external address and internal address which one is the receiver of the file (server) to the who sends the file (client).

Comment: if two computers are behind firewall/NAT the only way to establish a connection is to use some third party server